# Bitbucket pipelines, How could i access to another container?

Tags: docker, yii2, cypress, bitbucket-pipelines

I tried to build some testing process for my app, using Bitbucket pipelines.

The core testing tool is Cypress. I want to set up several docker containers and execute Cypress to test my app.

So, my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` looks like this:

```
image: docker:stable

options:
  docker: true

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Install PHP app
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - cp config/db.sample.php config/db.php
          - sed -i "s/[HOSTNAME]/db/" config/db.php
          - sed -i "s/[DB_NAME]/dbname/" config/db.php
          - sed -i "s/[DB_USER]/usr/" config/db.php
          - sed -i "s/[DB_USER_PASSWORD]/pass/" config/db.php
          - cp web/index.sample.php web/index.php
          - docker run --name db --restart always -e MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname -e MYSQL_USER=usr -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -d -p 3306:3306 mariadb
          - docker run --name web -v="$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR:/app" -d -p 8000:80 yiisoftware/yii2-php:5.6-apache
          - docker run --name e2e -v="$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR:/app" --workdir /app --tty -d cypress/base:10
          - docker exec -i web composer install
          - docker exec -i db mysql -uroot dbname < ./migrations/data/structure.sql
          - docker exec -i e2e yarn install
          - docker exec -i e2e yarn run cypress run --config baseUrl=http://web --project ./
        services:
          - docker
          - web
definitions:
  services:
    db:
      image: mariadb
    web:
      image: yiisoftware/yii2-php:5.6-apache
    e2e:
      image: cypress/base:10
```

Overall, it works almost good, but for some reason I can't get access to `web` service inside `e2e` container. I tried to use container name, like `http://web`, but it doesn't work. 
[image]
What is wrong here?

Comment: I think you forgot to add `e2e` in `services` serction

Comment: @LolWalid Thanks for comment, but still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like problem solved. I decided to create new image, which based on `yiisoftware/yii2-php:5.6-apache`, and manually install all deps:

- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Dependencies
- https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

So, after that i built an image and used it as image for web service in my config.
Service called `e2e` was removed.
Cypress tests execution looks like this:

```
docker exec -i web yarn run cypress run --config baseUrl=http://localhost:80 --project ./
```